# Modification in .js does not update in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Due to licensing issue, I will not be able to share the codes.

I was adding on validation to existing ones, and realized that even changing the existing validation's return value (a simple text msg) does not reflect on the browser. A quick summary, I was able to change any .html or .php file, just not .js files.
This project uses react too, not sure if this info helps.

Note that I have already cleared the cache of the browser many times as suggested by others.
May I know is there a mechanism where the creator can lock us out from changing the source code of .js files or a read-only code that don't accept addons/modification? If not, no methods to work around other than pointless refreshing.

Please note that the license only restricts the program to have n amount of users.
FYI- source code name is from IceHRM

Comment: Are you able to build and publish your changes successfully? Changing the source code does not necessarily mean it'll automatically start reflecting on browser. In theory, you'll probably need to build and deploy the code to be able to see the changes.

Comment: As this is a prebuild project that we bought, we only deploy it to our own localhost server to further modify it, if that answers your question

Comment: Is re-deploying post your changes successful? I am not entirely convinced that there can be a "readonly" code of sorts. What can potentially happen is your re-deployed assets may not be picked up by your server in case they are cached in-memory. (not browser cache, but server cache). Or if there is some hashing of sorts of your assets, then maybe redeployments is generating new hash which your HTML doesn't pick up.

Comment: Thanks, ill look into the server cache, and yes i doubt there's a "readonly" code too, just a possibility

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the issue behind why .js changes are not reflected. The project uses Gulp to bundle the js files, therefore any change to the code must use the command gulp to "compile it" just like how .java has javac

side note, it rarely has to do with client or server cache